# How can I create a constraint that allows multiple job assignments per machine in a Flexible Job Shop Problem?

Tags: python, constraints, or-tools, cp-sat

I am working on a flexible job shop problem that assigns machines (platforms) to jobs (targets) in a series of sequential tasks (phases). Currently, the problem is restricted (AddNoOverlap) so that a platform can only process one target per phase at a time, however I need the platforms to be allowed to execute a number of targets in accordance with the max_*targets _per _*platform matrix in the following reduced dataset below.

'''

```
# DATA
# assume 6 phases, 12 targets [3 type], 8 platforms [6 type]
targets = [  # phase = (processing_time, platform_id)
    [  # target 0
        [(50, 0), (25, 1), (50, 3), (75, 4), (75, 5), (23, 6), (45, 7)],  # phase 0 with 7 alt platforms
        [(5, 0), (25, 1), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (23, 6), (5, 7)],  # phase 1 with 7 alt platforms
        [(5, 0), (5, 1), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (4, 6), (5, 7)],  # phase 2 with 7 alt platforms
        [(5, 0), (25, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (5, 7)],  # phase 3 with 6 alt platforms
        [(25, 0), (25, 3), (23, 4), (30, 5), (30, 7)],  # phase 4 with 5 alt platforms
        [(5, 0), (10, 1), (5, 3), (5, 4), (10, 5), (10, 6), (10, 7)],  # phase 5 with 7 alt platforms
    ],
    [  # target 1
        [(50, 0), (25, 1), (50, 3), (75, 4), (75, 5), (23, 6), (45, 7)],  # phase 0 with 7 alt platforms
        [(5, 0), (25, 1), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (23, 6), (5, 7)],  # phase 1 with 7 alt platforms
        [(5, 0), (5, 1), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (4, 6), (5, 7)],  # phase 2 with 7 alt platforms
        [(5, 0), (25, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (5, 7)],  # phase 3 with 6 alt platforms
        [(25, 0), (25, 3), (23, 4), (30, 5), (30, 7)],  # phase 4 with 5 alt platforms
        [(5, 0), (10, 1), (5, 3), (5, 4), (10, 5), (10, 6), (10, 7)],  # phase 5 with 7 alt platforms
    ],
    [  # target 2
        [(50, 0), (25, 1), (50, 3), (75, 4), (75, 5), (23, 6), (45, 7)],  # phase 0 with 7 alt platforms
        [(5, 0), (25, 1), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (23, 6), (5, 7)],  # phase 1 with 7 alt platforms
        [(5, 0), (5, 1), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (4, 6), (5, 7)],  # phase 2 with 7 alt platforms
        [(5, 0), (25, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (5, 7)],  # phase 3 with 6 alt platforms
        [(25, 0), (25, 3), (23, 4), (30, 5), (30, 7)],  # phase 4 with 5 alt platforms
        [(5, 0), (10, 1), (5, 3), (5, 4), (10, 5), (10, 6), (10, 7)],  # phase 5 with 7 alt platforms
    ],
    [  # target 3
        [(50, 0), (25, 1), (50, 3), (75, 4), (75, 5), (23, 6), (45, 7)],  # phase 0 with 7 alt platforms
        [(5, 0), (25, 1), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (23, 6), (5, 7)],  # phase 1 with 7 alt platforms
        [(5, 0), (5, 1), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (4, 6), (5, 7)],  # phase 2 with 7 alt platforms
        [(5, 0), (25, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (5, 7)],  # phase 3 with 6 alt platforms
        [(25, 0), (25, 3), (23, 4), (30, 5), (30, 7)],  # phase 4 with 5 alt platforms
        [(5, 0), (10, 1), (5, 3), (5, 4), (10, 5), (10, 6), (10, 7)],  # phase 5 with 7 alt platforms
    ],
    [  # target 4
        [(25, 0), (25, 1), (25, 3), (35, 4), (35, 5), (23, 6), (45, 7)],  # phase 0 with 7 alt platforms
        [(5, 0), (25, 1), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (23, 6), (5, 7)],  # phase 1 with 7 alt platforms
        [(5, 0), (5, 1), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (4, 6), (5, 7)],  # phase 2 with 7 alt platforms
        [(5, 0), (25, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (5, 7)],  # phase 3 with 6 alt platforms
        [(15, 0), (15, 3), (13, 4), (25, 5), (30, 7)],  # phase 4 with 5 alt platforms
        [(5, 0), (10, 1), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (10, 6), (10, 7)],  # phase 5 with 7 alt platforms
    ],
    [  # target 5
        [(25, 0), (25, 1), (25, 3), (35, 4), (35, 5), (23, 6), (45, 7)],  # phase 0 with 7 alt platforms
        [(5, 0), (25, 1), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (23, 6), (5, 7)],  # phase 1 with 7 alt platforms
        [(5, 0), (5, 1), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (4, 6), (5, 7)],  # phase 2 with 7 alt platforms
        [(5, 0), (25, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (5, 7)],  # phase 3 with 6 alt platforms
        [(15, 0), (15, 3), (13, 4), (25, 5), (30, 7)],  # phase 4 with 5 alt platforms
        [(5, 0), (10, 1), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (10, 6), (10, 7)],  # phase 5 with 7 alt platforms
    ],
    [  # target 6
        [(25, 0), (25, 1), (25, 3), (35, 4), (35, 5), (23, 6), (45, 7)],  # phase 0 with 7 alt platforms
        [(5, 0), (25, 1), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (23, 6), (5, 7)],  # phase 1 with 7 alt platforms
        [(5, 0), (5, 1), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (4, 6), (5, 7)],  # phase 2 with 7 alt platforms
        [(5, 0), (25, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (5, 7)],  # phase 3 with 6 alt platforms
        [(15, 0), (15, 3), (13, 4), (25, 5), (30, 7)],  # phase 4 with 5 alt platforms
        [(5, 0), (10, 1), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (10, 6), (10, 7)],  # phase 5 with 7 alt platforms
    ],
    [  # target 7
        [(50, 0), (25, 1), (50, 3), (75, 4), (75, 5), (23, 6), (45, 7)],  # phase 0 with 7 alt platforms
        [(5, 0), (25, 1), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (23, 6), (5, 7)],  # phase 1 with 7 alt platforms
        [(5, 0), (5, 1), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (4, 6), (5, 7)],  # phase 2 with 7 alt platforms
        [(5, 0), (25, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (5, 7)],  # phase 3 with 6 alt platforms
        [(25, 0), (25, 3), (23, 4), (30, 5), (30, 7)],  # phase 4 with 5 alt platforms
        [(5, 0), (10, 1), (5, 3), (5, 4), (10, 5), (10, 6), (10, 7)],  # phase 5 with 7 alt platforms
    ],
    [  # target 8
        [(50, 0), (25, 1), (50, 3), (75, 4), (75, 5), (23, 6), (45, 7)],  # phase 0 with 7 alt platforms
        [(5, 0), (25, 1), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (23, 6), (5, 7)],  # phase 1 with 7 alt platforms
        [(5, 0), (5, 1), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (4, 6), (5, 7)],  # phase 2 with 7 alt platforms
        [(5, 0), (25, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (5, 7)],  # phase 3 with 6 alt platforms
        [(25, 0), (25, 3), (23, 4), (30, 5), (30, 7)],  # phase 4 with 5 alt platforms
        [(5, 0), (10, 1), (5, 3), (5, 4), (10, 5), (10, 6), (10, 7)],  # phase 5 with 7 alt platforms
    ],
    [  # target 9
        [(50, 0), (25, 1), (50, 3), (75, 4), (75, 5), (23, 6), (45, 7)],  # phase 0 with 7 alt platforms
        [(5, 0), (25, 1), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (23, 6), (5, 7)],  # phase 1 with 7 alt platforms
        [(5, 0), (5, 1), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (4, 6), (5, 7)],  # phase 2 with 7 alt platforms
        [(5, 0), (25, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (5, 7)],  # phase 3 with 6 alt platforms
        [(25, 0), (25, 3), (23, 4), (30, 5), (30, 7)],  # phase 4 with 5 alt platforms
        [(5, 0), (10, 1), (5, 3), (5, 4), (10, 5), (10, 6), (10, 7)],  # phase 5 with 7 alt platforms
    ],
    [  # target 10
        [(50, 0), (25, 1), (50, 3), (75, 4), (75, 5), (23, 6), (45, 7)],  # phase 0 with 7 alt platforms
        [(5, 0), (25, 1), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (23, 6), (5, 7)],  # phase 1 with 7 alt platforms
        [(5, 0), (5, 1), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (4, 6), (5, 7)],  # phase 2 with 7 alt platforms
        [(5, 0), (25, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (5, 7)],  # phase 3 with 6 alt platforms
        [(25, 0), (25, 3), (23, 4), (30, 5), (30, 7)],  # phase 4 with 5 alt platforms
        [(5, 0), (10, 1), (5, 3), (5, 4), (10, 5), (10, 6), (10, 7)],  # phase 5 with 7 alt platforms
    ],
    [  # target 11
        [(50, 0), (25, 1), (50, 3), (75, 4), (75, 5), (23, 6), (45, 7)],  # phase 0 with 7 alt platforms
        [(5, 0), (25, 1), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (23, 6), (5, 7)],  # phase 1 with 7 alt platforms
        [(5, 0), (5, 1), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (4, 6), (5, 7)],  # phase 2 with 7 alt platforms
        [(5, 0), (25, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (5, 7)],  # phase 3 with 6 alt platforms
        [(25, 0), (25, 3), (23, 4), (30, 5), (30, 7)],  # phase 4 with 5 alt platforms
        [(5, 0), (10, 1), (5, 3), (5, 4), (10, 5), (10, 6), (10, 7)],  # phase 5 with 7 alt platforms
    ],
]

num_targets = len(targets)
print(num_targets)
all_targets = range(num_targets)

platform = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
num_platforms = 8
all_platforms = range(num_platforms)

num_phases = 6
all_phases = range(num_phases)

# PLATFORM CAPACITY DATA
max_targets_per_platform = [  # target capacity per phase
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],  # platform 0
    [3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 3],  # platform 1
    [0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0],  # platform 2
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],  # platform 3
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],  # platform 4
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],  # platform 5
    [3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 3],  # platform 6
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],  # platform 7
]

# REQUIRED PHASE DATA
# input target KC Req - whether or not a phase is required in the killchain.  
targetKCReq = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],  # target 0
               [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],  # target 1
               [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],  # target 2
               [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],  # target 3
               [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],  # target 4
               [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],  # target 5
               [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],  # target 6
               [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],  # target 7
               [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],  # target 8
               [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],  # target 9
               [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],  # target 10
               [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]  # target 11]
'''
```

I have constructed a platform capacity constraint (#C2b) that is being seemingly ignored, and I believe it is because the capacity constraint needs to be included when the model is evaluating alternative intervals. I also have a AddNoOverlap constraint (#C2a) that currently prevents the Target 0 platform assignments from being made the same assignment for all targets. But I believe it needs to be altered to use as well (potentially to an AddCumulative), however that forces an assumption that all capacities are the same which they are not in this case.

How can I modify my code to allow for multiple (0-5 depending) targets per platform per phase?

Code:

'''

```
import collections

from ortools.sat.python import cp_model
from FJSP_Project import FJSP_data
import time #track time
lastTime = time.time()
startTime = lastTime

class SolutionPrinter(cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback):
    """Print intermediate solutions."""

    def __init__(self):
        cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback.__init__(self)
        self.__solution_count = 0

    def on_solution_callback(self):
        """Called at each new solution."""
        print('Solution %i, time = %f s, objective = %i' %
              (self.__solution_count, self.WallTime(), self.ObjectiveValue()))
        self.__solution_count += 1


def flexible_targetshop():
    """Solve a kill chain analysis problem."""

    #########################DATA############################
    #Data [I pull it in from a separate file, but it can also be pasted here in lieu of the below code]
    targets = FJSP_data.targets
    num_targets = FJSP_data.num_targets
    all_targets = FJSP_data.all_targets
    platform = FJSP_data.platform
    num_platforms = FJSP_data.num_platforms
    all_platforms = FJSP_data.all_platforms
    num_phases = FJSP_data.num_phases
    max_targets_per_platform = FJSP_data.max_targets_per_platform
    targetKCReq = FJSP_data.targetKCReq
    max_phases_simultaneous = FJSP_data.max_phases_simultaneous
    jam_sender_matrix = FJSP_data.jam_sender_matrix
    jam_receiver_matrix = FJSP_data.jam_receiver_matrix

    ########################MODEL###########################
    #Model the flexible targetshop problem.
    model = cp_model.CpModel()
    #Calculates max possible horizon to complete all targets by iterating through all alternatives
    #stored in max_phase_duration, horizon is the sum of all max_duration of each phase of each target
    #we may need to cap this in the future based on our max horizon constraint
    horizon = 0
    for target in targets:
        for phase in target:
            max_phase_duration = 0
            for alternative in phase:
                max_phase_duration = max(max_phase_duration, alternative[0])
            horizon += max_phase_duration

    print('Horizon = %i' % horizon)

    ####################DECISION VARIABLES & CONSTRAINTS############################
    #C1a: Phase Precedence
    #C1b:Phase Inclusion
    #C1c: Platform Availability (Jamming Status)


    # Global storage of variables. This creates a dictionary with default values of an empty list.
    intervals_per_resources = collections.defaultdict(list)
    starts = {}  # indexed by (target_id, phase_id).
    presences = {}  # indexed by (target_id, phase_id, alt_id).
    assigned_targets_per_phase = {}
    target_ends = []

    # Scan the targets and create the relevant variables and intervals.
    #This iterates over a set of targets and their phases to find max and min durations of each phase's alternative
    #target id loop iterates over each target in target dict, and consists of a list of phases
    #phase id iterates over phase in the phase list of the current target; min and max duration of each alt. in each phase are calculated and compared to the previous
    #stores the minimum and maximum durations
    for target_id in all_targets:
        target = targets[target_id]
        num_phases = len(target)
        previous_end = None

        # Initialize the platform target count variables to 0 for each phase.
        platform_target_counts = [[model.NewIntVar(0, max_targets_per_platform[platform_id][phase_id], f'target_count_t{target_id}_p{phase_id}_pl{platform_id}')
                                   for platform_id in range(num_platforms)] for phase_id in range(num_phases)]

        for phase_id in range(num_phases):
            if targetKCReq[target_id][phase_id] == 0:  # C1b: Skip phase if targetKCReq is 0
                continue
            phase = target[phase_id]

            # Get the maximum number of targets that can be processed by each platform in this phase.
            max_targets = [max_targets_per_platform[platform_id][phase_id] for platform_id in range(num_platforms)]

            min_duration = phase[0][0]
            max_duration = phase[0][0]

            # Create a variable to keep track of the number of targets assigned to each platform in this phase.
            assigned_targets = [model.NewIntVar(0, max_targets[platform_id], f'assigned_targets_p{phase_id}_pl{platform_id}') for platform_id in range(num_platforms)]
            assigned_targets_per_phase[(phase_id,)] = assigned_targets


            num_alternatives = len(phase)
            all_alternatives = range(num_alternatives)

            for alt_id in range(1, num_alternatives):
                alt_duration = phase[alt_id][0]
                min_duration = min(min_duration, alt_duration)
                max_duration = max(max_duration, alt_duration)

            # Create main interval for the phase.
            #NewIntervalVar creates a constraint that links start/duration/end together
            #May need to use NewIntVarFromDomain instead of NewIntVar (specific/given value vs specified/range)
            suffix_name = '_j%i_t%i' % (target_id, phase_id)
            START = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon, 'start' + suffix_name)
            DURATION = model.NewIntVar(min_duration, max_duration,
                                       'duration' + suffix_name)
            END = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon, 'end' + suffix_name)
            interval = model.NewIntervalVar(START, DURATION, END,
                                            'interval' + suffix_name)

            # Store the start for the solution.
            #creates an entry in a starts dictionary with the target/phase tuple and start time as a value to track start time of intervals
            #start was created above with NewIntvar; start time of current phase/target
            starts[(target_id, phase_id)] = START


        # C1a: Add precedence with previous phase in the same target.
            #this constraint enforces the interval between phases for the same target
            if previous_end is not None:
                model.Add(START >= previous_end)
            previous_end = END

            # Create alternative intervals.
            #for all alternatives, creates an ID variable indicating its existance, the start time, duration, end time, and interval
            #l presence indicates if the alt is chosen or not, l interval gives the start/end times if chosen, this is stored in a list
            if num_alternatives > 1:
                l_presences = []
                for alt_id in all_alternatives:
                    alt_suffix = '_j%i_t%i_a%i' % (target_id, phase_id, alt_id)
                    l_presence = model.NewBoolVar('presence' + alt_suffix)
                    l_start = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon, 'start' + alt_suffix)
                    l_duration = phase[alt_id][0]
                    l_end = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon, 'end' + alt_suffix)
                    l_interval = model.NewOptionalIntervalVar(
                        l_start, l_duration, l_end, l_presence,
                        'interval' + alt_suffix)
                    l_presences.append(l_presence)

                    # Link the primary/global variables with the local ones.
                    #if an alt is chosen, then the start/duration/end variables are equal (primary &alt)
                    #only one constraint for the choice, not primary and alternatives separately
                    model.Add(START == l_start).OnlyEnforceIf(l_presence)
                    model.Add(DURATION == l_duration).OnlyEnforceIf(l_presence)
                    model.Add(END == l_end).OnlyEnforceIf(l_presence)

                    # Add the local interval to the right platform.
                    #add alt intervals to the platform options per phase list
                    intervals_per_resources[phase[alt_id][1]].append(l_interval)

                    # Store the presences for the solution.
                    presences[(target_id, phase_id, alt_id)] = l_presence

                # Select exactly one presence variable.
                model.AddExactlyOne(l_presences)
            else:
                intervals_per_resources[phase[0][1]].append(interval)
                presences[(target_id, phase_id, 0)] = model.NewConstant(1)

        target_ends.append(previous_end)

    #C2a: No Overlap

    # No interval overlap on platforms: as is this is preventing every target having the same schedule
    #However this may also be preventing multiple targets across platforms where allowed by the following capacity constraint**
    for platform_id in all_platforms:
        intervals = intervals_per_resources[platform_id]
        if len(intervals) > 1:
            model.AddNoOverlap(intervals)

    #C2b: Platform Capacity- currently not effective (needs to be pulled into the interval creation)

    #platform capacity (this does not allow for differentiation between target types, just general platform capacity, current cap is at minmax)
    # create binary variables indicating whether a platform is processing a target during a phase
    TARGET_VARS = {}
    for t in range(len(targets)):
        for p in range(len(targets[t][0])):
            for f in range(len(targets[t])):
                TARGET_VARS[(t, p, f)] = model.NewBoolVar(f"target_{t}_platform_{p}_phase_{f}")

    # add constraint limiting the number of targets processed by each platform during each phase
    #(this also includes preventing platforms from executing phases it is not capable of)
    for p in range(len(targets[0][0])):
        for f in range(len(targets[0])):
            model.Add(sum(TARGET_VARS[(t, p, f)] for t in range(len(targets))) <= max_targets_per_platform[p][f])

 
 
######################OBJECTIVE FUNCTION#############################
    # Makespan objective
    makespan = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon, 'makespan')
    model.AddMaxEquality(makespan, target_ends)
    model.Minimize(makespan)

###################SOLVER###########################
    # Solve model.
    solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
    solver.parameters.max_time_in_seconds = 60  # 1 minute timelimit
    solution_printer = SolutionPrinter()
    status = solver.Solve(model, solution_printer)

########################PRINT SOLUTION##############
    # Print final solution.
    for target_id in all_targets:
        print('Target %i:' % target_id)
        for phase_id in range(len(targets[target_id])):
            if (target_id, phase_id) not in starts:
                continue  # skip this phase
            start_value = solver.Value(starts[(target_id, phase_id)])
            platform = -1
            DURATION = -1
            selected = -1
            for alt_id in range(len(targets[target_id][phase_id])):
                if solver.Value(presences[(target_id, phase_id, alt_id)]):
                    DURATION = targets[target_id][phase_id][alt_id][0]
                    platform = targets[target_id][phase_id][alt_id][1]
                    selected = alt_id
            print(
                '  phase_%i_%i starts at %i (alt %i, platform %i, duration %i)' %
                (target_id, phase_id, start_value, selected, platform, DURATION))

    print('Solve status: %s' % solver.StatusName(status))
    print('Optimal objective value: %i' % solver.ObjectiveValue())
    print('Statistics')
    print('  - conflicts : %i' % solver.NumConflicts())
    print('  - branches  : %i' % solver.NumBranches())
    #print('  - wall time : %f s' % solver.WallTime())


flexible_targetshop()

print("Data loaded. This operation took", round(time.time() - startTime, 2), "seconds.\n")

'''
```